# Изменить цвет имен файлов в PHPStorm

Tags: phpstorm, color

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Такой синий цвет выедает глаза и плохо видно название. Его можно изменить?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, можно

Откройте настройки, в строке поиска наберите `file status`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/file-status-highlights.html